# Why there is not a mobius transformation between those two domains? What is the general approach should I use?

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I am learning about conformal mapping, and I found it hard to answer question from the kind "determine if there exist mobius transformation between $A$ and $B$" for example:
$$A=\left\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid \operatorname{Im}(z)>0\right\}$$
$$B=\left\{z \in D_{1}(0) \mid \operatorname{Re}(z)>0\right\}$$

why there is not exist such transformation between those $2$ domains ? How should I approach this kind of questions?

How should I aproach this kind of questions?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Those domains *are* conformally equivalent. Both are simply connected, and therefore equivalent to the unit disk.

Comment: @MartinR clarification : Is this question is the same as ask "Is there exist mobius transformation between A and B"?

Comment: No. I understand “conformally equivalent” as “there is a conformal mapping between the domains.” That mapping need not be a Möbius transformation.

Comment: @MartinR Yes that what I understood as well I just wanted to make sure I am fine. this question appearned on a test for math majors and the original question was "determine if there exist mobius transformation between $A$ and $B$" The answer is there is not exist such transformation.

Comment: @MartinR thank you for your note, I edited my post and I hope it is clearer now

Comment: What do you know about Möbius transformations? What can the image of a half plane be?

Comment: @MartinR I know that cayley transformation is a mobius transformation that transfer the half plane into unit disk